# Get the first two words from a struct in PySpark data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql

```
data=[(("James","Bond"),["Java","C#"],{'hair':'black','eye':'brown'}),
      (("Ann","Varsa"),[".NET","Python"],{'hair':'brown','eye':'black'}),
      (("Tom Cruise",""),["Python","Scala"],{'hair':'red','eye':'grey'}),
      (("Tom Brand",None),["Perl","Ruby"],{'hair':'black','eye':'blue'})]
schema = ['n','ln','p']
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=schema)

+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+
|                n|             ln|                   p|
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+
|    {James, Bond}|     [Java, C#]|{eye -> brown, ha...|
|     {Ann, Varsa}| [.NET, Python]|{eye -> black, ha...|
|   {Tom Cruise, }|[Python, Scala]|{eye -> grey, hai...|
|{Tom Brand, null}|   [Perl, Ruby]|{eye -> blue, hai...|
+-----------------+---------------+--------------------+

name = df.select('n')
```

I tried the filter method to get the first and second names in a separate column, but it didn't work.

The desired output:

```
first |last
-----------
James |Bond
Tom   |Cruise
Tom   |Brand
```

Comment: "I tried the filter method". Where? I cannot see any filter in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column `n` is of `struct` data type. You can convert struct column to array, then join all the array's elements using space as delimiter `" "`. Then you can take the first and the second word after you `split` this column using the same delimiter.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

col_joined = F.array_join(F.array("n.*"), " ")
df = df.select(
    F.split(col_joined," ")[0].alias("first"),
    F.split(col_joined," ")[1].alias("last"),
)
df.show()
# +-----+------+
# |first|  last|
# +-----+------+
# |James|  Bond|
# |  Ann| Varsa|
# |  Tom|Cruise|
# |  Tom| Brand|
# +-----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
changed the schema according to the struct now I got another solution.


data=[(("James","Bond"),["Java","C#"],{'hair':'black','eye':'brown'}),
      (("Ann","Varsa"),[".NET","Python"],{'hair':'brown','eye':'black'}),
      (("Tom Cruise",""),["Python","Scala"],{'hair':'red','eye':'grey'}),
      (("Tom Brand",None),["Perl","Ruby"],{'hair':'black','eye':'blue'})]

schema2 = StructType([
    StructField('name',StructType([
        StructField('fname',StringType(),True),
        StructField('lname',StringType(),True)
    ])),
    StructField('lng',ArrayType(StringType()),True),
    StructField('properties', MapType(StringType(),StringType()),True)
])



df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=schema2)
df.select("name.fname","name.lname").show()

+----------+-----+
|     fname|lname|
+----------+-----+
|     James| Bond|
|       Ann|Varsa|
|Tom Cruise|     |
| Tom Brand| null|
+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).